# I am not able to import class in Android studios

Tags: android

I am not able to find a class called androidx.legacy.wiget.Space
I am making a text to speech converter app, and I am a beginner.
Please explain that how could I import it or fix this issue. I am writing in activity_main.xml file.

Comment: it is deprecated . you dont need it at all

Answer (score 0):

Add androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 in project dependencies section.

```
//app/build.gradle dependencies section

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
// Other dependencies
}
```

More Details : [AndroidX Class Mappings,AndroidX Artifact Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)